# Can we upload apk with different signed keystore after deactivate current apk in android

Tags: android, apk, keystore, signed

I want to upload apk with different signed keystore after deactivate current apk.
Actually company lost old one keystore that used for signed APK.
So any another way for get old keystore or upload new apk as Same app Update.

Comment: neither. When you signed with a different keystore, IMO, it will be a new application

Comment: See also: https://groups.google.com/g/android-developers/c/pocbQfvBdoU/m/xdixdYr7_WQJ

Answer (score 5):

As blackbelt stated, if you signed it with a different keystore, it will be a new application. So you should tell your users that they have to download the new version of the app.

However you could check this tool which will try to recover your private key with the alias. I don't guarantee that you could retrieve it but you could give a try.

> The tool recovers the key for your alias. By default this is the same
>   like the keystore password. Now there is an option to save
>   the key in a new keystore with the same password than the key! You can
>   use this, to sign your apk and update your app in the Playstore.

Here's the link :

https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/